# Join a report table based on three relational tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are the given tables:

```
`student`                  `subject`
-------------------        ------------------- 
id    name                 id    subject
-------------------        -------------------
1     Alice                1     Maths
2     Bob                  2     Science
3     Eve                  3     Economics
-------------------        -------------------

`marks`
-----------------------------------------------------
id     student_id      subject_id       marks
-----------------------------------------------------
1      1               1                30
2      1               2                40
3      2               3                50
4      3               1                60
5      3               2                70
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I need an output which should look like below:

```
`o/p`
----------------------------------------------
name          subject          marks
----------------------------------------------
Alice         Maths            30
Alice         Science          10
Alice         Economics        NULL
Bob           Maths            NULL
Bob           Science          NULL
Bob           Economics        50
Eve           Maths            60
Eve           Science          70
Eve           Economics        NULL
----------------------------------------------
```

Please note that I am targeting MySQL 5.6.x syntax and I have created a SQL fiddle of above [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b6b3) to ease access to the question.

Comment: We wouldn't normally call this a 'pivot'. It's a simple join.

Comment: @Strawberry question title updated

Comment: Here's a clue `SELECT ... FROM a_table x join another_table y left join a_third_table z ON z... =  x... AND z... = y....;

Comment: That's not helping since tables student and subject does not share a common column to join on! Joining these two in third `'on'` condition would be irrelevant.

Comment: I didn't provide a join condition for those tables. This IS the correct query.

Comment: Strawberry, do you think that in this case, because the question is a bit easy, the right path is to give hints as you did?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Isn't that self-evident?

Comment: @Strawberry `SELECT x.name, y.subject, z.marks FROM student x inner join subject y left join marks z ON z.student_id = x.id AND z.subject_id = y.id;` Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
select 
st.name,
su.subject,
m.marks
from student as st
cross join subject as su
left join marks as m on m.student_id=st.id and m.subject_id=su.id
order by st.name, su.subject
```

Comment: Couldn't figure this out earlier `left join subject as su on 1=1`. Thanks

Comment: @MilindDalvi There's nothing to figure out. It's the same as `JOIN subject su`

Comment: Yeah - sorry - deleted my comment when i realised!

Comment: agreed & changed

Comment: @Milind Dalvi `left join subject as su on 1=1` is actually a CROSS JOIN..

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT student.name,
       subject.subject,
       marks.marks 
    FROM student 
    JOIN subject ON student.id = subject.id
    JOIN marks ON student.id = marks.id 
    ORDER BY student.name,
             subject.subject
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's probably better to include more context/explanation.

Comment: This is incorrect as it will not show null marks for students.